# How to restrict oracle LIKE clause results

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, select, oracle11g

I have an Oracle table with 20 million users,
I would like to query the table for users with first name Like "Patel" or "Pat"  performance when querying using "like clause" is very bad.

```
select * from users  where first name like '%Patel%'  
Or
select * from users  where first name like '%Pat%'
```

And as far as I know if I will restrict the results by rownum - it will happen only after the LIKE - so I have a full table scan...
I don't want to scan the entire 20 Million records

```
select * from users  where first name like '%Pat%' where rownum<100
```

Is it possible to tell oracle to  stop after finding 100 rows?

Comment: Do you really need the leading wildcard?  It seems unlikely that you're really trying to find people whose first name has the string `Pat` in the middle.  If you remove the leading wildcard, then an index on `first_name` can (at least potentially) be used.  If you need the leading wildcard, then you're looking at building an Oracle Text index.

Comment: I would expect your query to work efficiently in Oracle.

Comment: Do you really need the leading wildcard?                                                                          yes.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle 12c (finally) introduced the `fetch first` syntax, which should perform a bit better:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  first_name LIKE '%Pat%' 
FETCH  FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: sorry, solution is needed for Oracle 11g let me tag it as such

Comment: While I agree this is nicer syntax, is it really likely to give any different execution plan than the ROWNUM filter?  In my experience, the optimizer has been ROWNUM-aware for quite some time, so it would attempt to choose a plan optimized for  returning a limited number of rows.  The problem here seems to be that there is simply no more efficient method for table access than a full scan.

Answer (score 2):

> select * from users  where first name like '%Pat%' where rownum<100

Oracle is smart enough to do everything for You. Execution plan for this query is:

```
SELECT STATEMENT, GOAL = ALL_ROWS      
     COUNT STOPKEY          
          TABLE ACCESS FULL
```

COUNT STOPKEY means that full scan will be stopped when Oracle will find enough  records to satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged Oracle 11g,  I'll give an answer that works in 11g.

Use the optimizer hint for first_rows_100 and wrap it into an inline view.

Example:

```
select *
  from (select /*+ opt_param('optimizer_mode','first_rows_100') */
              u.*, rownum as rn
          from users u
         where instr (name, 'Pat') > 0 or instr (name, 'Patel') > 0) inlineview
 where rn <= 100
```

Regards

Olafur